# How can I get more colours than the standard xcolor colours?

Tags: color

I need more colours than the standard colours of the package xcolor. I have also tried the dvipsnames xcolor package but it didn't work. Every time when I tried to highlight a text with color from from the package, like ForestGreen, my text became black. I would like to have a color like in the image.
Can anyone please help me?[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Try RGB 0,209,239

Comment: I don't think that the duplicate fits, but the question is clearly much to vage and unclear currently. Some code that shows what doesn't work is needed.

Comment: It looks like all he wants, really, is a way to obtain “more colours than the standard colours of the package xcolor”. There are numerous ways to achieve that.

Comment: Maybe you’d be interested in packages like `xcolor-material`, `xcolor-solarized`, and `xkcdcolors`?

Answer (score 3):

David Carlisle with his package [color](https://ctan.org/pkg/color), which belongs to the graphics-bundle, is one of the forerunners when it comes to colour support in LaTeX. Many other packages build on it.

A starting point in learning about commands for typesetting text in colour might be [section "3 Colour" of "Packages in the 'graphics' bundle" by David Carlisle and The LaTeX Project](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf#section.3), often referenced as grfguide.pdf. Packages like [xcolor](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf), too,  bring along the basic commands described there.

Probably the following example does help you?

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames,usenames]{color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\newcommand\PassColors[2][black]{%
  \fbox{%
    \colorbox{#2}{\textcolor{#1}{%
      \vbox to1cm{\vfill\hbox to 2.5cm{\hfill#2\hfill}\vfill}%
    }}%
  }\hskip.5em%
}%

\begin{document}

\enlargethispage{5mm}

\hrule height 0pt \vskip-4cm

{%
\large
\par\medskip\noindent
This is how you get colored text:
\fboxrule=3\fboxrule
\par\medskip\noindent
\verb|\fcolorbox{blue}{yellow}{\textcolor{red}{Test}}|: \fcolorbox{blue}{yellow}{\textcolor{red}{Test}}
\par\medskip\noindent
\verb|\colorbox{yellow}{\textcolor{red}{Test}}|: \colorbox{yellow}{\textcolor{red}{Test}}
\par\medskip\noindent
\verb|\textcolor{red}{Test}|: \textcolor{red}{Test}
\par\bigskip
}%


{%
  \fboxsep=0ex
  \fboxrule=2pt
  \par\bigskip\noindent
  {\large These are the colors provided by the option dvipsnames/according to dvips' color.pro:}
  \par\medskip\noindent
  \csname@for\endcsname\colors:=%
    {{GreenYellow}},{{Yellow}},%
    {{Goldenrod}},{{Dandelion}},{{Apricot}},{{Peach}},{{Melon}},{{YellowOrange}},{{Orange}},%
    {{BurntOrange}},{{Bittersweet}},{{RedOrange}},{{Mahogany}},{{Maroon}},{{BrickRed}},%
    {{Red}},{{OrangeRed}},{{RubineRed}},{{WildStrawberry}},{{Salmon}},{{CarnationPink}},%
    {{Magenta}},{{VioletRed}},{{Rhodamine}},{{Mulberry}},{{RedViolet}},{{Fuchsia}},{{Lavender}},%
    {{Thistle}},{{Orchid}},{{DarkOrchid}},{{Purple}},{{Plum}},{{Violet}},{{RoyalPurple}},%
    {{BlueViolet}},{{Periwinkle}},{{CadetBlue}},{{CornflowerBlue}},{{MidnightBlue}},{{NavyBlue}},%
    {{RoyalBlue}},{{Blue}},{{Cerulean}},{{Cyan}},{{ProcessBlue}},{{SkyBlue}},{{Turquoise}},%
    {{TealBlue}},{{Aquamarine}},{{BlueGreen}},{{Emerald}},{{JungleGreen}},{{SeaGreen}},%
    {{Green}},{{ForestGreen}},{{PineGreen}},{{LimeGreen}},{{YellowGreen}},{{SpringGreen}},%
    {{OliveGreen}},{{RawSienna}},{{Sepia}},{{Brown}},{{Tan}},{{Gray}},{[White]{Black}},{{White}}%
  \do{\expandafter\PassColors\colors}%
}%

\par\medskip\noindent
Note that when using the package \textbf{color} instead of the package \textbf{xcolor}, besides the option \textbf{dvipsnames}, after \textbf{dvipsnames} you also need to specify the option \textbf{usenames}.
\par\medskip\noindent
Note that document-classes like \textbf{beamer} and some packages internally load \textbf{xcolor} so that you need to specify options for \textbf{xcolor} already with the directives for loading these document-classes/packages.\\
Otherwise you might get errors about option-clashes and the like where with online-platforms like overleaf you need to view the so-called "raw log" for taking notice. The "raw-log" is the .log-file provided by the LaTeX-compiler itself while the LaTeX-compiler is running and what people asking for .log-file wish to see.

\end{document}
```